# How to calculate the unknown quantity in an infinite series?

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions, summation

[image]

[image]

I'd like to calculate x value in this equation.

Basically, I tried to 2 types of method which are FindRoot and NSolve.

But, I have failed the calculation caused by these errors up to now.

If there is anyone who knows this problems, plz let me know what I should do first!

Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: Please post code, not images. Or include images, but as a complement.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few problems with your code. Allow me to highlight them and guide you to a solution.

First of all, the proper way to define a function in Mathematica is using `:=`.
So your code should read

```
F[x_] := NSum[Exp[-x BesselJZero[0, a]^2]/BesselJZero[0, a]^2, {a, 1, Infinity}]
```

Furthermore, you should note that the zeroes of the Bessel function are increasing as `a` gets larger. Since you squaring and then taking a negative exponential, the terms in your series will rapidly decay and calculating only a finite number of terms will suffice. Therefore, you could also use the function

```
F2[x_, maxOrder_] := NSum[Exp[-x BesselJZero[0, a]^2]/BesselJZero[0, a]^2, {a, 1, maxOrder}]
```

and play with the `maxOrder` parameter. (In fact, for `x` equal to one the third term in the series equals `4.00479*10^-35`, which is smaller than machine precision, so a very low number of terms suffices). This will save you a lot of computing time.

Now, the error messages (at least the ones that say `... is not numerical ...`) that you receive have another origin, which can be found here: [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037).
In short, the problem is that the first step in the `FindRoot` algorithm is to evaluate the function symbolically, i.e. for an arbitrary `x`.
You can turn this off by explicitly demanding the argument of your function to be numeric, like this:

```
F3[x_?NumericQ, maxOrder_] := NSum[Exp[-x BesselJZero[0,a]^2]/BesselJZero[0, a]^2, {a, 1, maxOrder}]
```

The last point is that, as long as `x` is real, you are summing positive quantities and trying to equate them to something negative. When using a positive number:

```
FindRoot[F3[x, 5] == 0.014, {x, 0}]
```

Mathematica quickly finds the solution as

> {x -> 0.434665}

When you want the right-hand side of your equation to be negative, you should solve for `x` in the complex domain. In that case, I would suggest to split it into its real and imaginary parts, write `z=x+I y` and use for instance

```
FindRoot[{Re[F3[x + I y, 5]] + 0.014,Im[F3[x + I y, 5]]}, {{x, 0.1}, {y, 0.1}}]
```

which gives

> {x -> 0.434665, y -> 0.543228}

Comment: 0.014 ? -0.014?

Comment: In the second line of the question, a solution of `F[x]=-0.014` is sought. However, since `F[x]` is positive for real `x`, such a solution does not exist in the Reals. In the last coding example, I tried to explain how to look for such a solution in the complex plane. `Re[F[z]]==-0.014` is equivalent to `Re[F[x]]+0.014==0`, hence the +0.014 in the last example.